# Add a one-time-only user to a scheduled recurring meeting in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, scheduled-tasks, calendar

I have a weekly recurring meeting scheduled in Outlook (Mac, if it matters).  I want to invite a person to the next meeting, but not the subsequent meetings.  How can I do that short of creating a new meeting invitation just for them, or asking them to decline the meeting after they have attended?

Answer (score 2):

1. Double-click the meeting on your calendar to open it.(This will only open one occurrence instead of whole series)
   [image]
2. Change the attendees.
3. On the Organizer Meeting or Meeting tab, click Send Update.

This will only change this occurrence and do not affect subsequent meetings.